# Disable manual scrolling in UITextView while still allowing setting contentOffset programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` (+ some irrelevant views) inside a large `UIScrollView`.

The text inside the `UITextView` is scrolled programmatically using `setContentOffset` when the `UIScrollView` scrolls.

I want to disable manually scrolling of the text in the textView by the user while still maintaining the option to manually select text in text view.

I can't:
- set `scrollEnabled` to `false` as this breaks setting the `contentOffset`.
- set `userInteractionEnabled` to `false` as this disables the text   selection.

How can I disable the manual scrolling in the `UITextView` without side effects?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by subclassing `UITextView` and overwriting `-gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:`.